# Typekit Error "Adjusting Mac Style"

Tags: css

I get the following errors in my firefox-console when i use italic styles of a typekit font (din-2014).

```
downloadable font: OS/2: adjusting Mac style (regular) (font-family: "tk-din-2014-i2" style:italic weight:200 stretch:normal src index:0) source: https://use.typekit.net/af/a8689e/00000000000000003b9aee0b/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i2&token=1MThhP5l1O0ejpAro7ZFnw%3D%3D
```

[image: Image of my console]

Should i do something to solve this problem or can i just go on with it?

Comment: If I interpret the messages correctly, it says that there is an error in the italic font, so it can't be used, so the engine adjusts the style to use the regular font instead. (If my theory is correct, the browser would display a slanted version of the upright font rather than the italic font.) The thing to do is check if the font really does contain errors.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is generated by the OpenType Sanitizer (OTS) library which is included in Firefox.<sup>1</sup>

"The OpenType Sanitizer (OTS) parses and serializes OpenType files (OTF, TTF) and WOFF and WOFF2 font files, validating them and sanitizing them as it goes."<sup>2</sup>

To fix the warning you would need to change the font file.

You can verify that the font is still being applied using the Firefox inspector:

[image: Firefox inspector screenshot]

---

1. https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots/blob/2ecd07625c18dbc0f6b808d7565ed4448f064b52/src/os2.cc#L151
2. https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots